# how to show textbox if radio button value is checked from database?

Tags: php, jquery

I have 3 radio buttons

```
<input  type="radio" name="preferedpaymt" value="CheckMailed" id="CheckMailed1" <?php if($paymnt=="CheckMail") {?> checked="checked" <?php }?> />
(a)Check Mailed

<input  type="radio" name="preferedpaymt" value="PayPal"  <?php if($paymnt=="PayPal") {?> checked="checked" <?php }?> />
(b)By PayPal

<input  type="radio" name="preferedpaymt" value="WireTransfer"  id="WireTransfer" <?php if($paymnt=="wireTransfer") {?> checked="checked" <?php }?> />
(c)Wire Transfer To Bank A/c$12
```

But the value of radiobutton is checked from database . With these 2 tables are associated
if Radiobutton 2 is checked table1 1 should populate id tb1

here the problem is when a value of radio button is checked from database the table does not get populate if you only click it gets populated i want it automatis how can i do it?

jquery code, which I am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("input[name=preferedpaymt]").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "PayPal") {
            jQuery("#ppl").slideDown()
        } else {
            jQuery("#ppl").slideUp();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: -1 for not even bothering to post a clear question.

Comment: can you tell me how to post it i am new to this sir

Comment: @FrancisDCunha I've cleaned up the question. Please, next time when you post, reload the question you have posted and make sure your question and codes are visible. Also, please read the formatting help pages when posting.

Comment: Since he is new to the site, it wont be fair to down vote only because the question is not clear.

Comment: Thanks rahul and john and next time ill make sur that i post the question correctly.

Comment: @rahul I didn't do it because of the language issue, I did it because  the first POST was terrible. All the text was just dumped there. OP has asked 4 questions previously, so he should know by now. Also, I did try to remove my DV after my edits, but it was locked in :)

Comment: @Francis thank you for caring about that. Posting good questions helps you, the site and other people who come to the site for help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you culd use:

```
var chk_val = jQuery("input[name='preferedpaymt']:checked").val();
alert(chk_val);
```

**EDIT: how to use it!**

**Your inputs:**

```
<input  type="radio" name="preferedpaymt" value="CheckMailed" id="CheckMailed1" <?php if($paymnt=="CheckMail") {?> checked="checked" <?php }?> />
(a)Check Mailed

<input  type="radio" name="preferedpaymt" value="PayPal"  <?php if($paymnt=="PayPal") {?> checked="checked" <?php }?> />
(b)By PayPal

<input  type="radio" name="preferedpaymt" value="WireTransfer"  id="WireTransfer" <?php if($paymnt=="wireTransfer") {?> checked="checked" <?php }?> />
(c)Wire Transfer To Bank A/c$12
```

Then lets say you got one tables for each payment choise. ex:

**NOTE** All tables has the same classname this is because i want to hide all of them by default. The id attribute is set to "table_paymentmethod".

```
<table class="payment_table" id="table_CheckMailed" height="200" bgcolor="#00FF33" width="100px;" >
<tr>
  <td>

     You checked Checked mail
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="payment_table" id="table_PayPal" height="200" bgcolor="#FF0000" width="100px;" >
<tr>
  <td>

     You checked Paypal
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="payment_table" id="table_WireTransfer" height="200" bgcolor="#CCC" width="100px;" >
<tr>
  <td>

     You checked wiretransfer

  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now to the part where jquery comes in handy.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.payment_table').hide(); // Hide all tables by default

        var chk_val = jQuery("input[name='preferedpaymt']:checked").val(); // Grab the value of the selected radio

        jQuery('#table_'+chk_val).slideDown(1000); // Slides down the right table on page load.
  });
</script>
```

Well there you go, should do the trick for you. Im not the best at explaining but it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: i tried but the table is not getting automatically poped user

Comment: @Francis Check my last edit, it should solve the problem for you. :)